# &nbsp; is inserted instead of the white-space for the redactor-js

Tags: javascript, editor, whitespace, wysiwyg, redactor.js

Why `&nbsp;` is inserted instead of the white-space after inserting the second space in the row between two words or numbers, e.g. `1  2`. When I click on the HTML button I see `1&nbsp; 2`. I think it is correct behavior but I don't understand does this happen because of the browser or there's any flag in the code which turn it on? I didn't find any documentation for the redactor-js.

Please find the source code by link https://github.com/html5cat/redactor-js

Please find the redactor (a new version) by link https://imperavi.com/redactor/

Steps to reproduce:

1. open the link https://imperavi.com/redactor/
2. clear the redactor
3. write `1  2` (two spaces between)
4. click on the HTML button
5. check that there's `1&nbsp; 2` instead of `1  2`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its because in html when you have multiple spaces the browser will strip them out.

The &nsbp; is a html entity called a non-breaking space that allows programmers to over come this intended functionality.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

In this instance as its a WYSIWYG, it will replace multiple [space]'s with the html entity so that it displays as the user intends.

Specifically in this instance its handled by the browser and the "contenteditable" attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. But I knew all the things that you wrote. I don't understand if &nsbp; is added automatically by the browser or it's handled by the redactor?

Comment: Updated the answer to specify the attribute responsible.

Comment: Chris - THANK YOU A LOT!!! There's the 'contenteditable' attribute turned on in the redactor code.